# Почему куки устанавливаются как Session?

Tags: php, cookie

Устанавливаю Куки через php.  Использую данную запись:
`setCookie('usname', $_POST['name'], 2553454800, '/');`
При этом в отладчике Chrome они отображаются как Session.

Весь код:

```
 $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . 
 $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
 $user = json_decode($s, true);
 $name = $user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name'];
 $photo = $user['photo_big'];
 setCookie('usname', $name, 2553454800, '/');
 setCookie('usphoto', $photo, 2553454800,'/');
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте не жадничать и поставьте 2037 год, а не 2050

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Вроде помогло, спасибо. Если хотите, можете оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, что PHP (или браузер) не готов переварить дату больше чем `2^31` (это примерно 19 января 2038 года), так что нужно задавать время меньше этой даты.

Так что для «бесконечной» куки надо использовать 2147483647 (`2^31 - 1`).